# Python String to TimeZone Aware ISO8601 datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, pytz

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

some_date = "2019-01-01"
tzone = "America/Los_Angeles"
print(tzone)
iso_datetime = datetime.strptime(some_date , "%Y-%m-%d").replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tzone).isoformat()
```

Present output:

```
America/Los_Angeles
2019-01-01T00:00:00-07:53
```

Expected output (?): I checked on the internet, it says, Los Angeles is UTC-7:00. This is fine. But my python answers gives a weird answer `-07:53`. What is wrong here?

```
2019-01-01T00:00:00-07:00
```

Comment: Wrong way to use pytz. You need to use their localize function.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you show how?

Comment: @MarkRansom I got it now: `pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').localize(datetime.strptime("2022-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"))` gives `2022-01-01 00:00:00-08:00`

Comment: besides, Python >= 3.9 has [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) if you don't *have* to use pytz for some reason...